# Error creating SalesForce users LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:License Limit Exceeded

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

I want to create 5-6 SalesForce users programmatically in one go by using SOAP API. I am using Partner API and I have a Developer edition sandbox. I am retrieving users information from a database table and then by using API I want to create these 5-6 users at once. I can create one user however after creating another user it is throwing error `LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:License Limit Exceeded`.

This is snapshot of my code which retrieves users information from database and then creates a user programmatically:

```
SObject user = new SObject();

user.setType("User");

while (rs.next()) {
    user.setField("Alias", rs.getString("Alias"));
    user.setField("Email", rs.getString("Email"));
    user.setField("EmailEncodingKey", rs.getString("EmailEncodingKey"));
    user.setField("LanguageLocaleKey", "En_US");
    user.setField("LastName", rs.getString("LastName"));
    user.setField("LocaleSidKey", rs.getString("LocaleSidKey"));
    user.setField("TimeZoneSidKey", "America/Los_Angeles");
    user.setField("Username", rs.getString("Username"));
    user.setField("UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin", "false");
    user.setField("UserPermissionsMarketingUser", "false");
    user.setField("UserPermissionsOfflineUser", "false");
    user.setField("ProfileId", connection.getUserInfo().getProfileId());

    SaveResult[] results = connection.create(new SObject[] { user });
    System.out.println("Created user: " + results[0].getId());

    if (results[0].isSuccess())
        out.println("Created user: " + results[0].getId());
    else
        out.println("Error: " + results[0].getErrors()[0].getStatusCode() + 
                           ":" + results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());

}

QueryResult queryResults = connection
        .query("SELECT Id, Name from User "
                + "ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");

if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
    for (SObject s : queryResults.getRecords()) {
        out.println("Id: " + s.getField("Id") + " - Name: "
                + s.getField("Name"));
    }
}
```

Here I can create one user however after creating one user it is throwing error `LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:License Limit Exceeded`.

These are the number of licenses available:[image]

I can see that licenses remaining for SalesForce is 0. However, I just want to create some users that don't necessarily have to be SalesForce users. It can be any type of users which just should be able to login to my org. When I am trying to create some different type of users such as 'Chatter Free' which has 5000 licences by using `user.setField("UserType", "CsnOnly")` it is giving error `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE:Unable to create/update fields: UserType`

These are users in my SalesForce:
[image]

How to solve this problem? I just want to create some users from database which can then login to SalesForce. Its not necessary that they should be administrators. They can have minimum privileges but they should be able to login to SalesForce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a developer org, you won't be able to have more than two active users with Salesforce licenses. In order to create a user with a Chatter Free license, you should only need to assign them the profile of `Chatter Free User` - it will automatically set their license correctly based on the profile assigned to them (the `UserType` field is not editable).

Edit: to obtain the Chatter Free User's profile Id without hardcoding it (as it may change from org to org), you'll have to query it. I modified your code to include this query, as well as reworked it so that only a single callout to `PartnerConnection.create` is made (just a suggestion, as it will save overhead on your SOAP callouts):

```
QueryResult profileQuery = connection.query("select Id from Profile where Name = 'Chatter Free User' limit 1");
SObject chatterFreeProfile;
if ( profileQuery.getSize() > 0 ) {
    chatterFreeProfile = profileQuery.getRecords()[0];
}

ArrayList<SObject> users = new ArrayList<SObject>();
while (rs.next()) {
    SObject user = new SObject();
    user.setType("User");
    user.setField("Alias", rs.getString("Alias"));
    user.setField("Email", rs.getString("Email"));
    user.setField("EmailEncodingKey", rs.getString("EmailEncodingKey"));
    user.setField("LanguageLocaleKey", "En_US");
    user.setField("LastName", rs.getString("LastName"));
    user.setField("LocaleSidKey", rs.getString("LocaleSidKey"));
    user.setField("TimeZoneSidKey", "America/Los_Angeles");
    user.setField("Username", rs.getString("Username"));
    user.setField("UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin", "false");
    user.setField("UserPermissionsMarketingUser", "false");
    user.setField("UserPermissionsOfflineUser", "false");
    if ( chatterFreeProfile != null )
        user.setField("ProfileId", chatterFreeProfile.getField("Id"));
    else
        user.setField("ProfileId", connection.getUserInfo().getProfileId());
    users.add(user);
}

if ( users.size() > 0 ) {
    SaveResult[] results = connection.create(users.toArray(new SObject[users.size()]));
    for ( int i = 0; i < saveResults.length; i++ ) {
        if (results[i].isSuccess())
            out.println("Created user: " + results[i].getId());
        else
            out.println("Error: " + results[i].getErrors()[0].getStatusCode() + ":" + results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
}

QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, Name from User ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");
if ( queryResults.getSize() > 0 ) {
    for ( SObject s : queryResults.getRecords() ) {
        out.println("Id: " + s.getField("Id") + " - Name: " + s.getField("Name"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JCD for replying. How can I assign the profile of Chatter Free User in above code? Thanks again.

Comment: @waprau, see my updated answer - you'll need to query the `Id` field of the Chatter Free User profile in order to assign it to the User record's `ProfileId` field. In your original example, you were just assigning the inserted users to the profile of the user making the API connection, which in this case was Sys Admin.

Comment: Thanks JCD it worked. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. There are some typos in above code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `ProfileId` to a Profile associated with an available License Type, in your case to a Profile on the Chatter Free, Salesforce Platform, or one of your other available license types. Each Profile is tied to a particular UserLicense record, for example:

- 'SFDC' : Full Salesforce license
- 'CSN_User' : Chatter Free license
- 'AUL' : Salesforce Platform license

(To see more, do a Query All on the `UserLicense` object).

So you'll need to query for `Profile` records on available license types, and then associate this to your new users, e.g.

```
QueryResult profileQuery = connection.query(
    "SELECT Id FROM Profile "
    + "WHERE UserLicense.Name = 'Chatter Free' LIMIT 1"
);
SObject chatterFreeProfile;
if ( profileQuery.getSize() > 0 ) {
    chatterFreeProfile = profileQuery.getRecords()[0];
    user.setField("ProfileId", chatterFreeProfile.getField("Id"));
}
```